# Android enum with byte value

Tags: java, android

This is C# enum , I want to convert it into java with same byte type. please help   me on this.

```
    public enum DataType    { UNKNOWN                           = 0xFF, 
                              DATAUNAILABLE                     = 0x00,
                              NORMALBEAT                        = 0x01,
                              VFLUTTER                          = 0x02,
                              VFIB                              = 0x03,
                              VTACHY                            = 0x04,
                              ASYTOLE                           = 0x05,
                              PAUSE                             = 0x06,
                             };
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is android example:

```
package com.example.enumtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    enum DataType {
        UNKNOWN(0xff),
        DATAUNAILABLE(0x00),
        NORMALBEAT(0x01),
        VFLUTTER(0x02),
        VFIB(0x03),
        VTACHY(0x04),
        ASYTOLE(0x05),
        PAUSE(0x06);

        private final byte id;

        DataType(int id) {
            this.id = (byte) id;
        }

        public byte getId() {
            return this.id;
        }
    }

    private DataType type = DataType.PAUSE;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the output of these two values:

Comment: here Error showing:  The Constructor Datatype(int) is undefined  I tried with  DataType(byte id) {
        this.id = (byte) id;
    } . but this also didn't work. I am using this code for Android not java.

Comment: @user2710860 I've tested in android and it works fine. I updated my answer.

Comment: I am a big fan of using enum in C++, I tried your suggestion, but it is just not workable in Java. One needs to be able to assign such enum, which does not seem to be working, even after removing the final id and making the DataType constructor public. My personal conclusion: Java enum too limited to emulate C++ enum.

Answer (score 0):

I am replying to this post quite late but it can be useful to others who might come across a similar problem. For android, you need to  define a member variable with datatype Byte and invoke a constructor passing a Byte in the parameter list. I am a C++ developer also new to android programming and this is the first syntactical issue which I have faced.

```
 public enum test{          
 A1((byte) 0x00),       
 A2((byte) 0x01),       
 A3((byte) 0x02);       

 private byte test;     

 test(byte test) {      
     this.test = test;  
 }
```

}